# scanf in function seems to be writing garbage values to one array but not the other, despite both being identical

Tags: c, arrays

So in the function getRoster, I have two arrays that are defined in the same way in main and called in the same way. But for some reason, one of the scanf functions write garbage data to the array so that in line 91 (A debugging line in this case) one value is the one I entered and the other is seemingly random. I've checked this code top to bottom already to see if there were any notations that I added to one array and not the other, and I can't seem to find a single one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getRoster(int *jerseyNumbers[10], int *playerRatings[10])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &jerseyNumbers[i]);
        printf("Enter player %d's rating\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &playerRatings[i]);
    }
}

void updateRating(int *jerseyNumbers[10], int *playerRatings[10])
{
int i, n = -1, hold;
printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
scanf("%d", n);
for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    if(jerseyNumbers[i]==n)
        hold = n;
if (n=-1);
printf("Error");

printf("Enter a new rating for player:\n");
scanf("%d", &playerRatings[n]);
}

void aboveRating()
{

}

void replacePlayer()
{

}

void  outputRoster(int *jerseyNumbers[10], int *playerRatings[10])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("Player %d  -- Jersey number: %d , Rating: %d \n", i+1, jerseyNumbers[i], playerRatings[i]);

    }

 }

void menu(int *jerseyNumbers[10], int *playerRatings[10])
{
    char menuInput;
    printf("\nMENU\n");
    printf("u - Update player rating\n");
    printf("a - Output players above a rating\n");
    printf("r - Replace player\n");
    printf("o - Output roster\n");
    printf("q - Quit\n");
    printf("\nChoose an option:\n");


    scanf(" %c", &menuInput);
    if (menuInput == 'u')
        {updateRating(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'a')
        {aboveRating();
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'r')
         {replacePlayer();
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'o')
        {outputRoster(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'q')
        printf("Reached Quit");
    else
        printf("Input Error\n");

}

int main()
{
    int *jerseyNumbers[10];
    int *playerRatings[10];
    char menuInput;
    int quitFlag = 0;
    getRoster(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);
    printf("%d %d", jerseyNumbers[0], playerRatings[1]);
    menu(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: `int *jerseyNumbers[10]` is effectively `int **jerseyNumbers`. Now think about what `&jerseyNumbers[i]` would mean.

Comment: why do you need "int *jerseyNumbers[10]" to hold only 10 integer ?. it should be "int jerseyNumbers[10];" i think.

Comment: When you use `getRoster(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);` in `main()`, you are passing the address one beyond the end of the arrays, which is not what you intended and leads to undefined behaviour when you use the pointers. You have arrays of `int` pointers; you never allocate the `int` values for the pointers to point at.  That's another source of trouble.  You pass the same addresses to `menu()` — more trouble. Then, inside `menu()`, you call, for example, `updateRating(&jerseyNumbers[10], &playerRatings[10]);` — this passes an address 10 beyond the already bogus addresses passed in.

Comment: Have you tried `fflush()` before `scanf`?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to @NaveenKumar and @DeiDei's comment to your question. 
Actually, the logic of your program is alright. But where you've gone wrong is the syntax regarding how you have declared the arrays and passed them as arguments to the functions. I have listed the changes to be made below:

1. First of all Dylan, do not declare an array as: `int
   *jerseyNumbers[10]` and `int *playerRatings[10]`. For the regular array which you actually need, just declare as:

   a. `*jerseyNumbers` and `*playerRatings`... Remove the size. OR

   b. `jerseyNumbers[10]` and `playerRatings[10]`... Remove the `*` from the declaration.
2. When you're passing these arrays as arguments to a function, don't ever send it how you've done. Just pass the array name as an argument. Like this: `getRoster(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);` and `menu(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);`.
3. In the function definition, the parameters representing the array should be either `*arrayname` or `arrayname[size]`. Since we have used the first during declaration, use the same here as follows:

   `void getRoster(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings) {...}`,

   `void updateRating(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings){...}`,

   `void  outputRoster(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings) {...}`,

   `void menu(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings) {...}`.
4. And as @PaulSm4 has suggested don't use the semi-colon at the end of an `if` conditional. Though this isn't the cause of your problem here, it is a practice you need to follow and mistake to be avoided.

I have attached the working code below, along with the output.

**CODE**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getRoster(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter player %d's jersey number\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &jerseyNumbers[i]);
        printf("Enter player %d's rating\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &playerRatings[i]);
    }
}

void updateRating(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)
{
int i, n = -1, hold;
printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
scanf("%d", n);
for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    if(jerseyNumbers[i]==n)
        hold = n;
if (n=-1)
    printf("Error");

printf("Enter a new rating for player:\n");
scanf("%d", &playerRatings[n]);
}

void aboveRating()
{

}

void replacePlayer()
{

}

void  outputRoster(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        printf("Player %d  -- Jersey number: %d , Rating: %d \n", i+1, jerseyNumbers[i], playerRatings[i]);

    }

 }

void menu(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)
{
    char menuInput;
    printf("\nMENU\n");
    printf("u - Update player rating\n");
    printf("a - Output players above a rating\n");
    printf("r - Replace player\n");
    printf("o - Output roster\n");
    printf("q - Quit\n");
    printf("\nChoose an option:\n");


    scanf(" %c", &menuInput);
    if (menuInput == 'u')
        {updateRating(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'a')
        {aboveRating();
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'r')
         {replacePlayer();
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'o')
        {outputRoster(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);
        }
    else if (menuInput == 'q')
        printf("Reached Quit");
    else
        printf("Input Error\n");

}

int main()
{
    int jerseyNumbers[10];
    int playerRatings[10];
    char menuInput;
    int quitFlag = 0;
    getRoster(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);
    printf("%d %d", jerseyNumbers[0], playerRatings[1]);
    menu(jerseyNumbers, playerRatings);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
> Enter player 1's jersey number  
> 1 
> Enter player 1's rating  
> 10 
> Enter player 2's jersey number  
> 2 
> Enter player 2's rating  
> 20 
> Enter player 3's jersey number  
> 3 
> Enter player 3's rating  
> 30 
> Enter player 4's jersey number  
> 4 
> Enter player 4's rating  
> 40 
> Enter player 5's jersey number  
> 5 
> Enter player 5's rating  
> 50 
>
> 1 20 
>
> MENU 
>
> u - Update player rating 
> a - Output players above a rating 
> r - Replace player 
> o - Output roster 
> q - Quit
>
> Choose an option:  o 
> Player 1  -- Jersey number: 1 , Rating: 10 
> Player 2  -- Jersey number: 2 , Rating: 20  
> Player 3  -- Jersey number: 3 , Rating: 30  
> Player 4  -- Jersey number: 4 , Rating: 40 
> Player 5  -- Jersey number: 5 , Rating: 50
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You say "when you declare an array as: `int
*jerseyNumbers[10]` and `int *playerRatings[10]`, you are declaring 2-d arrays" — No!  Those are declared as arrays of pointers, which are not the same as 2D arrays, though you can use double subscripts to access both.  You are correct to diagnose that there is a problem there, but the problem you diagnose is wrong.  Your fix is correct — or one of a few correct notational fixes.

Comment: Okay @JonathanLeffler, will make the edit. Thanks for the info. by the way is it a pointer to the array or array of pointers?.

Comment: The notation `int *name[10]` is an array of 10 pointers to `int`.  The notation `int (*name)[10]` is a (single) pointer to an array of 10 `int`.  Quite different!

Answer (score 0):

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Get in the habit of using curly braces often - even when you don't need them.

```
void updateRating(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)  
  // You probably only need a pointer or an array - but probably not both ;)
{
  int i, n = -1, hold;
  printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
  scanf("%d", n);
  for (i=0; i<5; ++i) {  // Curly brace here...
    if(jerseyNumbers[i]==n)  { // And here...
        hold = n;
    }
  }
  if (n=-1) {  // BUG ALERT: deleted ";" (and added a brace)
    printf("Error");  // BUG ALERT: fixed this by removing ";"?
  } else {
    printf("Enter a new rating for player:\n");
    scanf("%d", &playerRatings[n]);
}
```

Or perhaps better:

```
void updateRating(int *jerseyNumbers, int *playerRatings)  
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
  scanf("%d", n);
  printf("Enter a new rating for player:\n");
  scanf("%d", &playerRatings[n]);
}
```

And, as  Rishikesh Raje correctly pointed out:

> The definition of the array's and the function calls for OP is also
>   not correct. Please mention this also.

Comment: The definition of the array's and the function calls for OP is also not correct. Please mention this also.

Comment: My problem seems to be coming from either getRoster or main, as updateRating is an optional function that I have not yet finished

Comment: @Dylan Wolfer - 1) Change your array definitions (e.g., change to `int jerseyNumbers[10];`, instead of a pointer to an array), 2) Adjust your function signatures for the new array definitions, 3) Fix the ";" and add curly braces cited above ... and let us know what happens then